# How to create fake files with specific formats on linux?

Tags: linux, file-type

I'm testing some file types recognition on my website, if the user uploads a .txt file it loads a txt icon, if he uploads a .jpg file is loads another icon.

I don't want to upload real wmv, avi, mp3, mp4 and any other big files, so I'm thinking: there's a way to create a fake 1KB file with any filetype?

I'm using Linux, so changing file extensions obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Use the `file` command to test the files after you generate them with whatever program.  But they need to be actual files of whatever type.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching various tools,I'd recommend you to try using required portion of the files that you are already having. This may not be the best method but it will make your work faster.

You can run,

> dd if=/path/to/original_file of=/path/to/new_file bs=1024 count=1

Thus you will get exact 1 kb file of the type you want.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

For text files, `touch` will work. You may wish to differentiate between plain text and, for instance, C source code, by parsing the file extension.

ImageMagick can create various image file formats using something like:

```
convert -size 1x1 xc:white test.jpg
```

where the file extension matches the file format (e.g., .jpg -> JPEG). A list of formats it supports can be found with

```
identify -list format
```

I don't know of any swiss army knives for generating sound files as I've never really looked into it. Maybe take a look at `siggen` for generating WAV files. From there, you should be able to get everything else. For instance, for MP3, take a look at `lame`.

Beyond that, I'm not sure. There may be similar programs for the other file formats.